# DataTables Individual Column searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

Is it possible to combine the `Select Inputs` and the `Text Inputs`? I use DataTables on several tables, always the same initialization. I would like to chose the column for the `Select Inputs` by the column header since the column that I want the select list on is not always in the same position. Then all the others I want to have the `Text Inputs`. This way I'll have one column that has the `Select Inputs` and all others that have the `Text Inputs`.

I have been able to implement the different [Select](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) and [Text](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) Inputs from these two examples. But I'm not good enough with jquery and javascript to figure out how to select the right column for the `Select Input` and have all the others be `Text Inputs`. The tables that I use can be anywhere from 3 columns to 75+ columns. And I want to select the column by the header name for the Select input.

And on top of all of this, is there a way to make the `Select Input` a MultiSelect Input? I am having it a selector for the state and would like to be able to select multiple states at once.

Here are the two different ways I've used for the `Select` and `Text` input:

```
initComplete: function ()
{
    this.api().columns([1]).every(function ()
    {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function ()
                {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    var strVal = val.replace("<div class='Scrollable'>", '');
                    strVal = strVal.replace("<\/div>", '');
                    column
                        .search(strVal ? /*'^' +*/ strVal /*+ '$'*/ : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j)
        {
            var strValue = d.replace("<div class='Scrollable'>", '');
            strValue = strValue.replace("<\/div>", '');
            select.append('<option value="' + strValue + '">' + strValue + '</option>')
        });
    });
}
,
initComplete: function ()
{
    var api = this.api();

    // Apply the search
    api.columns().every(function ()
    {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function ()
        {
            if (that.search() !== this.value)
            {
                that
                      .search(this.value)
                      .draw();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**EIDT**

Using @Gyrocode's suggestion from below I now have this:

```
initComplete: function ()
{
    var api = this.api();

    // Apply the search
    api.columns('.dt-filter-text').every(function ()
    {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function ()
        {
            if (that.search() !== this.value)
            {
                that
                  .search(this.value)
                  .draw();
            }
        });
    });
    api.columns('.dt-filter-select').every(function ()
    {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
            .on('change', function ()
            {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.excapeRegex(
                    $(this).val()
                );
                var strVal = val.replace("<div class='Scrollable'>", "");
                strVal = strVal.replace("</div>", '');
                column
                    .search(strVal ? /*'^' +*/strVal /*+ '$'*/ : '', true, false)
                    .draw();
            });
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, J)
        {
            var strValue = d.replace("<div class='Scrollable'>", '');
            strValue = strValue.replace("</div>", '');
            select.append('<option value="' + strValue + '">' + strValue + '</option>')
        });
    });
}
```

This almost works. When I select a value from the selector in the State column it doesn't search. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I don't know what.

Also, it is not getting all the states, only the ones on the first page. Is there a way to get all the states or perhaps to have an array that will hold all the values that I need since the states are not likly to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify column indexes for `columns()` API method to target specific columns.

For example:

```js
initComplete: function ()
{
    // Initialize dropdown filter in second column
    this.api().columns([1]).every(function ()
    {
       // ... skipped ...
    });

    // Initialize text filter in first, third and fourth column
    this.api().columns([0, 2, 3]).every(function ()
    {
       // ... skipped ...
    });
}
```

However, instead of dealing with column indexes, I would assign a class name to each `th` element where you want a text box (`dt-filter-text`) or dropdown (`dt-filter-select`). Then you can supply a selector to `columns()` API method, for example `columns('.dt-filter-text')` or `columns('.dt-filter-select')`.

Comment: This is great! Now though the selector is only getting the first value and not all the values that would be in that field. Since I know the states that are available can I make a list that I can put in there?

Comment: And now the search isn't working for the selector only for the text boxes?

Answer (score 4):

I've got it working. Just be sure to add classes to the header, like so:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="dt-filter-text">Name</th>
        <th class="dt-filter-select">Position</th>
        <th class="dt-filter-select">Office</th>
        <th class="dt-filter-text">Age</th>
        <th class="dt-filter-text">Start date</th>
        <th class="dt-filter-text">Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // DataTable
    $('#table').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {

            //Apply select search
            this.api().columns('.dt-filter-select').every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });
                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d,j) {
                    select.append('<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>')
                });
            });

            //Apply text search
            this.api().columns('.dt-filter-text').every(function () {
                var title = $(this.footer()).text();
                $(this.footer()).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />');
                var that = this;
                $('input',this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Add this to CSS if you want to place the footer directly below the header:

```
#table tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```